# Is there a "non-linear algebra"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

We use matrices to describe systems of linear equasions and in general operations on objects, that preserve equal distances between points, of which they consist. I never really understood, why we can't or are not willing to apply non-linear operations on matrix-like objects. I wonder if this area of math exists and what its' main principles are.

Comment: How about matrix exponentials?

Comment: Perhaps the study of smooth manifolds is a natural next step beyond linear algebra.

Comment: We **do** apply non-linear operations to matrices. Lie algebras are vector spaces of matrices (Ado's theorem) satisfying the "Jacobi identity": a nonlinear operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply more general, non-linear operations on things like vectors or matrices - but the theory becomes a lot richer and more complex very very quickly!

Let's look at a fairly simple extension: how about we look at polynomials instead of linear functions/matrices? Polynomials are as simple as it gets, but:
Consider the polynomial function $p(x, y) := x^2+y^2+1$. From Linear Algebra, we know that a single (non-degenerate) linear function on $\mathbb{K}^2$ would have a one-dimensional kernel (i.e., $\ker L = \{ (x, y) \mid L(x,y) = 0 \}$ would be a one-dimensional subspace) for every field $\mathbb{K}$, but for $p$, this already depends on the field: if $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$, $p(x,y) \ge 1$ for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so $\ker p$ would be empty(!), but for $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$, we get an infinite space of solutions (which, with an appropriate notion of dimension, turns out to be one-dimensional).

Extending the ideas of Linear Algebra to polynomials is the starting point of Algebraic Geometry, a massive and highly active research subject.

But maybe you want to generalize even more? What you get will now depend on what kind of functions you allow, and what spaces you are working in. You might be interested in looking at what Complex Analysis, Differential Geometry and Real Analysis do to matrices and vector spaces.